# Не выдаются права в контейнере docker postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker

Создаются юзер и таблицы, но права не выдаются. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема - уже голову сломал:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:12-alpine
COPY src/main/resources/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

init:

```
CREATE DATABASE rootdb;
\c rootdb;

CREATE USER root WITH PASSWORD 'root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE rootdb TO root;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO root;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.students (
    id          INT             GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME        VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    COURSE      VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.emails (
    ID      INT            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    email   varchar(255)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    STUDENT_ID    INT    REFERENCES STUDENTS(ID)
);
```

При подключении root к бд и попытки сделать выборку прав:

```
select * from emails;

ERROR:  permission denied for table emails
SQL state: 42501
```

Причем если запустить повторно

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO root;
```

То все ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала создавайте таблицы, а уже потом давайте права.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES` дает права на все существующие таблицы, а не на те, которые будут созданы в будущем.

Второй вариант это сделайть пользователя владельцем БД `ALTER DATABASE rootdb OWNER TO root`. В этом случае у него будет доступ ко всем объектам в БД.

Comment: А если мне нужно дать права на бд таким образом , чтобы при создании таблиц не нужно было каждый раз выдавать права?

Comment: Сделайте чтобы пользователь владел БД. `ALTER DATABASE rootdb OWNER TO root`